# Google Custom Search with transparent background

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger, google-custom-search

I am embedding a custom google search into my blogger site using `layout -> add a gadget -> html/javascript`.

However, the search box has a white background. How can I make the background transparent?

[image: Copying the code for the google search.]

[image: The google box has a white background.]

[image]

As you can see in the last screenshot, there is no option for the background color of the search box. Is there any other way to make it transparent?

Comment: Blogger CSS https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/175740?hl=en   Can demonstrate with details how to change, if u can?

Comment: Find the `div` that contains the google custom search, then change the `background` property.

Comment: What to do? No google custom search in  
Blogger CSS https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/175740?hl=en

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear and more easily answerable. If you are not happy with my edits, feel free to undo them.

Comment: Got any amend code to make Google Custom Search, background transparent?

Answer (score 1):

Miscommunication! U so-called professional should simply say, 
"Refer to Google Custom Search & click CSS source file."

Search for 'background-color' Then change: 
background-color: transparent;

That's the answer! 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to Blogger, but works on a regular non-Blogger web page.  Simply add the following to the head section of your page:

```
<style>
    .cse .gsc-control-cse,
    .gsc-control-cse {
      background-color:transparent !important;
    }
</style>
```

You can also take a look at the [full CSS page of Google's default styles that can be overridden here](https://cse.google.com/cse/style/look/v2/default.css).  When you override any particular style, be sure to use the !important attribute, as shown above.