# What is the color code for background transparency in google custom search xml?

Tags: xml, transparent, google-custom-search

Need to customize google custom search box. as i plan to use transparent background and background boarder which is my color code....

here the code,

```
  <LookAndFeel nonprofit="false" element_layout="8" theme="7" custom_theme="true" text_font="&quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;, sans-serif" url_length="full" element_branding="show" enable_cse_thumbnail="true" promotion_url_length="full" ads_layout="1">
<Logo />
<Colors url="#008000"
        background="?????????"
        border="???????????" 
        title="#0000CC" 
        text="#000000" 
        visited="#0000CC" 
        title_hover="#0000CC" 
        title_active="#0000CC" />

<Promotions title_color="#0000CC"
            title_visited_color="#0000CC" 
            url_color="#008000" 
            background_color="#FFFFFF" 
            border_color="#336699" 
            snippet_color="#000000" 
            title_hover_color="#0000CC" 
            title_active_color="#0000CC" />

<SearchControls input_border_color="#000000" 
                button_border_color="#000000" 
                button_background_color="#999999" 
                tab_border_color="#0000CC" 
                tab_background_color="#E9E9E9" 
                tab_selected_border_color="#FF9900" 
                tab_selected_background_color="#FFFFFF" />

<Results border_color="#FFFFFF" 
         border_hover_color="#FFFFFF" 
         background_color="#FFFFFF" 
         background_hover_color="#FFFFFF" 
         ads_background_color="#fff7f5" 
         ads_border_color="#FFFFFF" />
```

Need value to transparent the background and boarder.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple solutions here: [Google Custom Search with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942538/google-custom-search-with-transparent-background)

"Refer to Google Custom Search & click CSS source file.
Search for 'background-color'
Change:  background-color:transparent